# mysql result is not correctly written to file using java applet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, applet, jnlp

I am trying to do an example to write to a file the database records using java applet. But the problem is after running the applet i'm seeing the file is created but it contains garbage data. 
I've signed my applet (following this tutorial : http://www.narendranaidu.com/2007/11/3-easy-steps-to-self-sign-applet-jar.html)
I've tried putting mysql-connector in the created jar(SaveToFile.jar). But the same thing happened. So I am confused if the database connection is happening really.

After build, my project structure looks like the following(here i'm showing just the builded part):

```
appletTest/
    out/production/appletTest/
                             applet/SaveToFile.class
                             SaveToFile.html
                             SaveToFile.jar
                             mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
                             file-applet.jnlp
                             keystore
```

After opening the html file to Firefox browser(chrome is not giving any response, don't know why!) and by giving the permission to applet to run, the data.txt file is created successfully in this same directory.

Here is the Java code:

```
package applet;

    public class SaveToFile extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        try {
            getData();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/APPLET?user=root&password=root&characterSet=utf8&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&characterSetResults=utf8";
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM applet" );
            try {
                String text = "";
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    text += rs.getString("title");
                }
                writeToFile(text);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                    ignore.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile (String text) {
        try {
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data.txt"));
            dataOut.writeUTF(text);
            dataOut.close();
        } catch(Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
        <information>
        <title>Write To File</title>
        <vendor>Vendor</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"
          href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
          max-heap-size="128m"/>
        <jar href="SaveToFile.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <applet-desc name="Test Applet"
         main-class="applet.SaveToFile"
         width="22"
         height="22"/>
    <update check="background"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
</jnlp>
```

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Applet Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attributes = { code:'applet.SaveToFile',  width:22, height:22} ;
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'file-applet.jnlp'} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
</script>
<applet
        id="saveToFile"
        width=22
        height=22
        code="applet.SaveToFile"
        archive="SaveToFile.jar"
        jnlp_href = 'file-applet.jnlp'
        />
</body>
</html>
```

And finally here is the mysql table:

```
+----+--------+
| id | title  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | TITLE1 |
|  2 | TITLE2 |
|  3 | TITLE3 |
|  4 | TITLE4 |
+----+--------+
```

Even I've tried this query (following this : http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/) but nothing happened this time:

```
SELECT * FROM applet
INTO OUTFILE 'tmp/data.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Besides it will be helpful if anybody can give an an example about something secured in handling database interaction in between javascript and applet.

Thank You

Comment: As far as I can tell you haven't described the actual problem. You even say _'the data.txt file is created successfully'_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I said the file contains garbage data which it should not have.

Comment: Define garbage (show a sample of it). That last query will have created the file on the server, not on the client.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: This is the garbage written on my file: Ȁ摤

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Some times this one : 鸀佃啌乍ㄠ㴠䴠䅹灰敬䍴䱏䵕⁎′‽祍灁汰瑥佃啌乍ㄠ㴠䴠䅹灰敬㉴佃啌乍㈠㴠䴠䅹灰敬㉴佃啌乍ㄠ㴠䴠䅹灰敬㍴佃啌乍㈠㴠䴠䅹灰敬㍴佃啌乍ㄠ㴠䴠䅹灰敬㑴佃啌乍㈠㴠䴠䅹灰敬㑴

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I'm successfully done with this problem. I've extracted the mysql-connector and put all those extracted files along with the applet class file in the archive jar and the mysql data retrieval is working good now. Here is the commands I've used in windows (under the builded part):

```
appletTest/
    out/production/appletTest/    

mkdir tmp
cd tmp
jar -xf ../mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
cd..
jar -cvf SaveToFile.jar applet\SaveToFile.class -C tmp/ .
rmdir tmp /S
```

And using the created jar file as archive is doing things right with database.